# apply median filter on pixels of a certain value?

Tags: python, list, numpy, filter

I Have a matrix with int inside it.

I need to replace the `111` with the median of its immediate 4 neighbourhood if any of the neighbors are  `111` then they are ignored.

For eg:-

```
matrix = 1   2   3   4   5   6
         101 111 1   3   44  3
         111  3  4   4   5   6
          1    2 4   5   7   7

after replacing expected op 
1   2   3  4  5  6
101 2.5 1  3  44 3
3  3  4   4   5   6
1    2 4   5   7   7
```

My code is pretty bad and probably very slow. any help appreciated

```
def median_fil_mat(matrix):
    rows,columns= np.where(matrix==111)
    r,c=np.shape(matrix)
    for each_row in rows:
        for each_colmn in columns:
            if each_row==r-1:
                r1=[each_row-1]
            elif each_row>0 & each_row!=r-1:
                r1= [each_row-1,each_row+1]
            else:
                r1=[each_row+1]

            if each_colmn ==c-1:
                c1=[each_colmn-1]
            elif each_colmn >0 & each_colmn!=c-1:
                c1=[each_colmn-1,each_colmn+1]
            else:
                c1=[each_colmn+1]
            med_lis=list()
            for rr in r1:
                for cc in c1:
                    med_lis.append(matrix[rr,cc])
            med_lis=[x for x in med_lis if x!=111 ]
            matrix[each_row,each_colmn]= np.median(med_lis)
    return matrix
```

Comment: Are you intentionally iteratively updating each element as you are processing? Let's say you update an element at `(x1,y1)` position because it has one `111` in its neighborhood. Then, you process the next element `(x1,y+1)` which also happen to have one `111` in its neighborhood. Now the previous element happen to be in the neighborhood of this current element. So, would you use the previous element's `(x1,y1)` updated value or the original value to update the current element `(x1,y1+1)`?

Comment: yeah Ideally I should not do that and replace all the neighboring 111 with the median calculated in the same style described above. But I dont know How I could do that so doing it this way.

Comment: Maybe initialize an output array with a copy of the input array and update the output array with each iteration? Would that give you the expected results?

Comment: Use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(array):
     if array[2]==111:
         return np.median(array[array!=111])
     else:
         return array[2]
fp = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
a = np.fromstring("""1   2   3   4   5   6
         101 111 1   3   44  3
         111  3  4   4   5   6
          1    2 4   5   7   7""", sep=" ").reshape((4, 6))
generic_filter(a, func, footprint=fp, mode='nearest')
```

Returns

```
array([[   1. ,    2. ,    3. ,    4. ,    5. ,    6. ],
       [ 101. ,    2.5,    1. ,    3. ,   44. ,    3. ],
       [   3. ,    3. ,    4. ,    4. ,    5. ,    6. ],
       [   1. ,    2. ,    4. ,    5. ,    7. ,    7. ]])
```

Comment: (Almost, noticed small problem...)